# How to use JSON API? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

What am I doing wrong to get this error?

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError]

This is what the link looks like:

[image: link]

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=4798",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(results){
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

By using `dataType: 'json',` instead of `dataType: 'jsonp',`, I get this error instead:

[image: json error]

Additional Info about using the API by the host:
http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Grand_Exchange_APIs#GE_Item_price_information

Comment: The server is not returning a jsonp result, just plain json.  See this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7116090/507793

Comment: The response mime type is also `text/html`, not sure if that can create issues.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying a type of "jsonp", but that response looks like plain JSON to me.

JSONP is a particular way of *sending* JSON which wraps the data in a callback function as a way of getting around the "same-origin" security policy. As [this article on the jQuery site](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) describes it, it is "a consensual cross-site scripting hack".

It has to be supported by the service you're retrieving from; you'll have to check their docs for how to get them to send it. If they can't, you will have to grab their JSON with a server-side script, which you can then use like a proxy by running AJAX calls against your own script.