# Restrict access to spring REST data based on credentials

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data

I have a CrudRepository throug which I can access my entities. Let's say I have an entity called Report (all oversimplified and not compiling):

```
@Entity
public class Report{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private boolean classified;
   private Date date;
   private String reportdata;
}
```

And a CrudRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "reports", path = "report")
public interface ReportRepository extends CrudRepository<Report, Long>
{
   findByDate(Date date); // <---- I want this to return only reports which are not classified for users who do not have the appropriate role
}
```

The findByDate will return all reports, including all classified reports for all users making the request. I want to restrict the access to the data based on the currently authenticated user. Is this possible?

Comment: yes its possible, use spring security `@PostFilter` annotations, details here http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/el-access.html

Comment: @MangEngkus `@PostFilter` will screw up pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Spring Security 4. It now integrates with Spring Data.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#data

Something like:

```
@Repository
public interface ReportRepository extends CrudRepository<Report,Long> {

    @Query("select r from Report r where r.date=?1 and r.owner.id = ?#{ principal?.id }")
    Report findByDate(Date date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

REST is stateless. It means that the server stores **NO** runtime informations (session, role etc.) about client. So if you want to use REST you should generate an API key for you client. Use a simple path filter to check whether the API key valid or not.

But perhaps you mean [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115940/difference-between-ajax-restful-rest-json-and-jsonp) ?

Comment: Sorry but your comment makes no sense. Who says I'm storing runtime information? My client sends a JSON web token with his credentials which I want to use to verify the access to the data. But the answer of @MangEngkus has pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @meerlol sorry, i was a little confused bit by your `currently authenticated user`. In your case you have authenticated request and not user. But the comment makes anyway sense. Like I said use filter to check the permission.